# Spring MVC Web App with Default user

Tags: java, database, configuration, spring-mvc

I am developing a web app using Spring MVC and Hibernate that I hope to package up as a WAR file and distribute for users to deploy where needed.

The application will require the database connection details before deploying, can anyone advise on the best practice of how to do this? currently my database.properties file is packaged as part of the WAR file, is there an easier way than asking the user to manually edit this file inside the WAR file or in the source and then expect them to build the war file themselves?

I would also like an easy way for users to create a single admin user on first deploy easily - is it best to just provide a sql script to create that or is there a way to include the functionality in the web app so on first deploy it creates the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since web applications are not focused to "mass production", I can't tell if something like that is possible.

You can make an SQL script containing all your CREATE statements limited by "IF NOT EXISTS" to avoid deleting existing data. Hibernate can execute a sql script at the moment of creating the SessionFactory, if Hibernate finds a file named "import.sql" located in the classpath root, Hibernate will execute it. Also you can always edit the database.properties of an application already deployed without re-packaging the WAR.

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to edit a database.properties file from within a deployed running application? I was thinking it could default to an in-memory DB setup, allowing the user to deploy and log on, and then they could edit the DB properties to point to the correct database via some web UI admin panel?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't answer before, sure you can make a page (a form) to manage the settings, though as i said you'll need to restart the application. I'm not sure about how you can accomlpish a context restart but anyway I hope that you resolve this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try Liquibase, http://www.liquibase.org/ . It does not allow your users to setup database connection details but it allows you to manage the database schema (create and update the schema) and default data.

Comment: Thanks - does this also cater for the first scenario regarding control of the application database.properties config file?

Comment: No, not really. My answer is misleading for that part, I will edit it. But once you have the database connection setup it creates or updates the database, adds default data etc.